# throwing an error : Non-resolvable parent POM for com.synectiks:search:[unknown-version]

Tags: pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.synectiks</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>search</artifactId>
    <name>Synectiks Elastic Search</name>
    <description>Module to hold elastic search module.</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.synectiks</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-libraries</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

throwing an error:   Non-resolvable parent POM for com.synectiks:search:[unknown-version]

Comment: This was the error message.

Comment: Confirm you parent groupId "com.synectiks" and parent artifactId "parent". Is that correct?

Comment: yes it is correct only

Comment: could u give any suggestions please